# Parsing subscripts when loading package files via the FrontEnd

Tags: front-end, import, packages, system

I am working on some code, and have found it easier to use a *Mathematica* package because

- it is easier to run via command-line (lightweight)
- it allows for easier source versioning (Git), and
- it allows me to use another text editor for indentation alignment (for me, the *FrontEnd* does not behave too well in this regard).

I notice that it parses the package files and substitutes symbol escape sequences `\[MathSymbol]`, but it does not parse out subscripts.

I can add subscripts in when editing via the *FrontEnd*, but once I save it and reload it, the subscripts are simply represented as `InputFormat[]`.

I looked through the *Option Inspector* for parsing options and found the `DefaultPackageStyleDefinitions` at

```
$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Package.nb
```

EDIT: Four years later, but yes, I agree with the comments below in that I did not specify a clear question. Thinking back, my question here was:
Is there a way to have the *FrontEnd* display symbols rather than their long-form version?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the FrontEnd's package editor?

Comment: Yes, I am using the FrontEnd editor.

Comment: This just isn't supported in the FE.  The FE tries very hard not to put unreadable typesetting markup into packages to facilitate easy exchange with other programming editors.  Possibly workarounds...putting the code in a notebook with an auto-save package would work, but then the package file is no longer the primary source file, and that probably won't satisfy you.  You could post-process the save file, but that seems dicey to me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this would introduce unreadable typesetting. To my understanding, the FE would only need to evaluate 1st-level children of a `Symbol[]` expression in-place to return the math-style subscript expression. When it saves the file, it would simply save as it normally does, as `Subscript[A, ...]` in plain-text.

Comment: To clarify, I meant that the FE should only evaluate the head `Symbol[]` of an expression in-place, holding any child expressions so it only changes type-setting. Couldn't edit after 5 minutes, meh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's a fair answer to this topic, which doesn't really state any  question precisely. Also, hard to find more authoritative source.

> This just isn't supported in the *FrontEnd*. The *FE* tries very hard not to put unreadable typesetting markup into packages to facilitate easy exchange with other programming editors.
>
> Possibly workarounds...putting the code in a notebook with an auto-save package would work, but then the package file is no longer the primary source file, and that probably won't satisfy you. You could post-process the save file, but that seems dicey to me.
>
> –John Fultz Oct 25 '12 at 6:05